# What is ApplicationDomain.domainMemory for?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, applicationdomain

In AS3, what is `ApplicationDomain.domainMemory` for?

http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/system/ApplicationDomain.html#domainMemory

Comment: Great question - especially with Adobe's new ["Premium" features](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/premium-features.html) in the player that are tied to this function!

Comment: "Premium" features, lol, AKA "DRM" AKA "intentionally non-functional software that needs fixed by a hacker".  Glad they got rid of those: "As of January 2013, Adobe is no longer classifying the XC APIs as a Premium Feature." "There are currently no public Premium Features in the Flash runtimes."

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This defines a ByteArray for the use with fast memory access which currently unfortunately can only be used by Adobe Alchemy or using Joa Ebert's TDSI helper project or Haxe. For regular ActionScript this has no use.

http://blog.joa-ebert.com/2008/12/01/alchemy-actionscript-asc/

http://ncannasse.fr/blog/adobe_alchemy

http://www.unitzeroone.com/blog/2009/05/22/another-scream-on-flash-alchemy-memory-and-compilers/