# Modifying the domain memory of a loaded SWF to control behavior

Tags: actionscript-3, arrays, swfloader, applicationdomain

I have several flash games that cannot be paused from within the games. I would like to write a wrapper swf that allows me to pause them. It is not feasible to recompile the games, so no functionality can be added to them.

What I would probably need to do is control when the loaded swf gets ENTER_FRAME events and redirect calls to flash.utils.getTimer to a function defined in the wrapper. Can this be done by modifying the domainMemory ByteArray of the loaded ApplicationDomain object?

Answer (score 0):

`domainMemory` is definitely doesn't help you, [it's just](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3664643/what-is-applicationdomain-domainmemory-for) the API to access to the fast memory.

What you can try to do is to decompile the game swf and find the dispatcher of main EnterFrame event (and after loading game swf you have to find this dispatcher through the display list for example if it doesn't turned out to be the stage or root), that is used as the game tick dispatcher, than you will be able to intercept the default EnterFrame event for this dispatcher. For interception just add your own listener with the higher priority:

```
//pause the game
dispatcher.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onGameEnterFrame, false, 1);
//resume the game
dispatcher.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onGameEnterFrame);

protected function onGameEnterFrame(event:Event):void
{
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
}
```